# Single transistor buffer and low pass filter

Tags: audio, analog, bjt, buffer

I want to build an input buffer for audio purposes.
This buffer should do 3 things:

1. have high input / low output impedance.
2. divide the signal by 2.
3. low pass filter the signal (cut freq. = 15KHz).

How about the circuit below?? Any other suggestion? Please let me know if you have better ideas.

Would it be ok to use a MOSFET like the BS270 instead of the bjt?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftxQtE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: One challenge is that the BC547C is obsolete. Can you be more specific than 'high' input impedance? Do you need 100k such as in a typical guitar amp input?

Answer (score 2):

You are over-thinking this.  Here is all you need:

[image]

This satisfies all your specs:

> have high input / low output impedance.

The input impedance is 2.2 kΩ and the output impedance 550 Ω.

> divide the signal by 2.

It does that, since it is basically a resistor divider with two equal resistors.

> low pass filter the signal (cut freq. = 15KHz).

Assuming you really mean kilo-Hz, not Kelvin-Hz as you wrote it, this is accomplished by C1 working against R2.  The rolloff frequency is

1 / (2 Π R C) = 14.5 kHz

which is within 4% of the target, and considerably less than the tolerance of ordinary parts.

This circuit has additional advantages over something like what you show:

The gain is more accurate since there is no additional attenuation thru a emitter follower.

It doesn't require power.

It is more linear.  The B-E voltage of your circuit isn't completely fixed or a linear function of the output voltage.  As a result, the emitter follower is slightly non-linear.

Answer (score 1):

DC bias must always be a smaller R than load.

ie. R3 must be << AC coupled load  e.g. <1/2 load R to avoid large swing current starving Ie.

Then Rb must be biased to Vcc/2 such that Req<< hFE* Re for hFE=150 Re/Rb<100

Thus ...

R4 =   100 Ohm is your load with \$R4C1=1/(2\pi f)\$
This needs a large C1.  A bipolar supply avoids this.

[image: schematic]

You can divide signal /2 easily but you forgot to ensure DC bias >> load AC current.

BS270 needs a Vgs of >3V for a drain follower so no good. Vgs(th)=1V ok.

Define Zin , Zout and Vin pp , f range and Av better next time.

This one has Zin=1k.

Bootstrapping can raise Zin with extra cap to split bias input, if needed, but I do not recommend as this limits BW severely in this low voltage, low impedance.

Comment: Recommendation: Use bootstrapping for drastically increasing the input resistance (bootstrapping: positive feedback between emitter and base). Start a google search for "emitter follower bootstrap methods".

Comment: Maybe but not needed.  also, No results found for "emitter follower bootstrap methods".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me what is the best way to add low pass filtering in this buffer stage? Would it be ok to add the capacitor at the base of the bjt?

Comment: Base coupling capacitors make a highpass function.

Comment: Tony Stewart - I cannot believe that you did not found anything about bootstrap for emitter followers via google.

Comment: @LvW I did but "explicit examples" with plurals often fail. You ought to know that I already know about bootstrapping and why it fails in this circuit due to raising the output impedance as well, which is contrary to what is needed.

Comment: @Dukenukem  If there is no input HF signal then LPF is not needed.

Comment: @Tony Stewart, I am afraid you are in error. Bootstrapping will cause - as desired - a drastical increase for the input resistance but will have a rather low influence on the output resistance of the emitter follower - depending on the source resistor Rs of the signal source. In your circuit with Rs=0 the influence will be very small and, thus, is in no way an argument against the bootstrapping method. I can provide examples.